# Не отображается картинка.

Tags: css

Привет всем! У меня есть кусочек кода CSS

```
{ background: url(images/answer-tag.png); display: block;
```

Но он не отображаеться. Путь к файлу правильный. CSS файл находиться в папке CSS, а картинка в images. Если путь к картинке вставляю в обычный HTML, то идет. Почему он не отображет картинку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что высоту и ширину блока вы не указали.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ background: url(../images/answer-tag.png); }
```